Prove that $R^2$ never decreases when new variables are added to the model.
My idea:
Suppose we have two models: Model 1 with $p$ predictors, and Model 2 with $p+1$ predictors.
The coefficient of determination $R^2$ is given by
$$
R^2 = \frac{SSR}{SST} = 1 - \frac{SSE}{SST}
$$
For the first model, we have
$$
R^2_1 = 1 - \frac{MSE_1 \cdot (n - p)}{SST}
$$
While for the second model,
$$
R^2_2 = 1 - \frac{MSE_2 \cdot (n - p - 1)}{SST}
$$
The intuitive idea is that the second term of $R^2_2$ will be subtracted from a smaller value compared to $R^2_1$. To understand this, I need to analyze what happens to $MSE_1$ and $MSE_2$.
That is where I'm stuck.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976747/prove-that-r2-cannot-decrease-when-adding-a-variable?rq=1
