Proving that $R^2$ can not decrease when adding new variables
I am trying to prove that $R^2$ can not decrease when adding new variables using matrix.
My try:
Suppose that we have two models:
$$Y = X\beta + u$$
where for the $X$ is an matrix of observables, $\beta$ is a vector of coefficients and $u$ is a vector of error. And supose for the second model that we add a new variable $Z$, getting
$$Y = Z \beta_z + X\beta + v$$
So, my aim is prove that the $\hat u' \hat u \geq \hat v' \hat v \Leftrightarrow R^2_u \leq R^2_v$.
\begin{align}
\hat v' \hat v &= (Y - \hat Y_v)'(Y - \hat Y_v)\\
  &= (X\beta + u - X\hat\beta - X_0 \hat\beta_0)'(X\beta + u - X\hat\beta - X_0 \hat\beta_0)\\
  &= \underbrace{(X (\beta - \hat\beta) - X_0\hat\beta_0)'(X (\beta - \hat\beta) - X_0\hat\beta_0)}_{A} + 2u'(X (\beta - \hat\beta) - X_0\hat\beta_0) + u'u\\
  & = A + 2u'X (\beta - \hat\beta) - 2u'X_0\hat\beta_0 + u'u
\end{align}
How $\beta$ is obtained OLS, so $u'X = 0'$.Then
\begin{align}
\hat v' \hat v &= A - 2u'X_0\hat\beta_0 + u'u\\
\end{align}
But now, I don't know how to progress.
Any suggestions?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976747/prove-that-r2-cannot-decrease-when-adding-a-variable?rq=1
